# Export a gif from Processing in Python mode

Tags: python, export, processing, gif

I'm using [Processing](https://processing.org/) in [Python mode](https://py.processing.org/) to make a little animation, and I would like to export it as a gif.

If I were coding in javascript, I could use [gifAnimation](https://extrapixel.github.io/gif-animation/), put I am using python mode, I can't seem to make it work.
I could use PIL or Pillow, but that would basically require writing another program.

Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be clear about libraries with Processing Python mode:

- You can use "pure Python" libraries;
- You can't use Python libraries with C extensions & etc (like `numpy`);
- You can't use JavaScript (or p5js) libraries;
- You can use Java & Processing Java mode libraries!

Art Simon has a nice example of gifAnimation export here: https://github.com/APCSPrinciples/AnimatedGIF/

**A step by step approach:**

1. Download the `gifAnimation` library from:
   https://github.com/extrapixel/gif-animation/archive/3.0.zip
2. Unzip and copy the gifAnimation folder into your libraries folder, like this:
   `user/sketchbook/libraries/gifAnimation` (Linux) or
   `user/Documents/Processing/libraries/gifAnimation` (Mac/Windows)
3. Restart the IDE and add this at the start of your sketch:

```py
add_library('gifAnimation')
```

4. Initialize an exporter object inside `setup()`

```py
def setup():
    global exporter
    size(400, 400)
    exporter = GifMaker(this, "animation.gif")
    exporter.setRepeat(0)     # infinite repeat
    exporter.setQuality(100)  # test values
    exporter.setDelay(200)    # milliseconds
```

5. at the end of `draw()` use the `.addFrame()` method and maybe something for the end of the animation recording.

```py
def draw():    
    # your drawing here

    exporter.addFrame()

    if keyPressed and key == 'e':
        exporter.finish()
        print("gif saved, exit")
        exit()
```