# Creating GIF but cannot see filenames os glob

Tags: python-3.x, processing, gif, glob

Goal: export this output as a GIF.

This is working code, using **[Processing](https://processing.org/)** and Python.

I am stuck with reading the image filenames to create a GIF.

I downloaded `gif-animation-3.0` and placed it in `libraries` folder.

---

Attempted Solution:

```py
import random
import glob
import os

add_library('gif-animation-3.0')
radius = 0

def setup():
    global displayWidth, displayHeight, radius, num_frames
    size(displayWidth, displayHeight)
    background(0)
    noFill()
    stroke(255, 0, 0, 10)
    radius = height / 2
    num_frames = 0
    
    global exporter
    size(400, 400)
    exporter = GifMaker(this, 'Examples/spiral-waves.gif')
    exporter.setRepeat(0)     # infinite repeat
    exporter.setQuality(100)  # test values
    exporter.setDelay(200)    # milliseconds 
    
def draw():
    global num_frames
    num_frames += 1
    print(num_frames)
    global radius
    center_x = width / 2
    center_y = height / 2
    
    beginShape()
    for i in range(360):
        _noise = noise(i * 0.02, float(frameCount) / 50)
        x = center_x + radius * cos(radians(i)) * _noise
        y = center_y + radius * sin(radians(i)) * _noise
        curveVertex(x, y)
        
        if radius == 0:
            stroke(0, 0, 225, 25) # Blue
        if radius == 100:
            stroke(0, 225, 0, 25) # Green
        if radius == 200:
            stroke(225, 0, 0, 10) # Red
            
    endShape(CLOSE)
    radius -= 1
    saveFrame('####.png')
    
    if num_frames == 10:
        noLoop()
        exporter.addFrame()
        exporter.finish()
```

Console:

```
Maybe there's an unclosed paren or quote mark somewhere before this line?
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I should add to post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215718/export-a-gif-from-processing-in-python-mode

Comment: Does the message say where the error is? Now the last part of your code is a triple quoted string which won't execute.

Comment: I've just installed `gifmaker` Python package and it worked fine for me. Usage - see `https://neuropoly.github.io/gifmaker/usage/`

Comment: @DmitryMesserman How can I make a gif that's faster to go through images?

Comment: I have no experience with `gifmaker` package.

Comment: It's not offered as an option. I will search for that final step. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install gifmaker`

`gifmaker -i *.png`